# Apex:repeat option is repeating element multiple times

Tags: visualforce, html-area-component

I'm using Apex repeat and including check-box field and check-box value. 
Here is the Apex code.

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!providerCategories}" var="pc">    
      <label>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!pc.optionSelected}" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!pc.optionLabel}" />
      </label>
     </apex:repeat>
```

When I run this code I am getting label for both check-box field and check-box value

```
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id28:ProviderSearch:j_id43:0:j_id45" checked="checked"><label>Expert Advisory Board </label>    </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id28:ProviderSearch:j_id43:1:j_id45" checked="checked"><label>Medical Facility</label>                         </label>
```

I don't need label for check-box value. How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.
I want output like this

```
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id28:ProviderSearch:j_id43:0:j_id45" checked="checked">Expert Advisory Board  </label>
```

Comment: try to remove label markup.

Comment: I want enclose both in one label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, it sounds like you don't want the label to render. If so, perhaps you want to try something like this:-

```
<apex:repeat value="{!providerCategories}" var="pc">      
    <label>
       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!pc.optionSelected}" id="someId" />
       <apex:outputLabel value="{!pc.optionLabel}" for="someId" rendered="false" />
    </label>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!providerCategories}" var="pc">    
  <label>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!pc.optionSelected}" id="someId"/>
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!pc.optionLabel}" for="someId"/>
  </label>
 </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: no luck.. Didn't work

Comment: @PraveenMP Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have checkbox and its corresponding text value to be wrapped inside a label then you should use just the bind variable after checkbox like below

```
<apex:repeat value="{!providerCategories}" var="pc">    
  <label>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!pc.optionSelected}" />
    {!pc.optionLabel}
  </label>
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope it helps.